# "collection element of type BOOL" is not an objective-c object

Tags: ios, objective-c

Anyone have a clue why I am getting this?

```
-(void)postPrimaryEMWithEM:(EM *)em
              exclusive:(BOOL) isExclusive
                 success:(void (^)())onSuccess
                 failure:(void (^)())onFailure {


if(self.accessToken) {


    GenericObject *genObject = [[GenericObject alloc] init];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:genObject
                                          path:@"users/update.json"
                                    parameters:@{
                                                  ...
                                                 @"em_id"  : ObjectOrNull(em.emID),
                                                 @"exclusive": isExclusive  <-- error message
```

Comment: would this work `(void)postPrimaryEMWithEM:(EM *)em
              exclusive:(BOOL) isExclusive
                 success:(void (^)())onSuccess
                 failure:(void (^)())onFailure`

Comment: No it does NOT. I tried that first.

Comment: Should `isExclusive` be a `BOOL *` and not just a `BOOL`? You may actually have two issues here. Using `BOOL *` is fine if the goal of the parameter is to give a value back to the caller.

Comment: `BOOL*` is a pointer to a `BOOL`.  There are legit places to use this, but this isn't one of them.  Skip the `*`.  (And try to learn a bit more about the difference between a "thing" and a "pointer to a thing" -- it's critical to understand that to program in Objective-C.)

Comment: @jgervin You fixed the parameter to the `postPrimaryEMWithEM` method, but you still need to use the `@(isExclusive)` syntax (or `[NSNumber numberWithBool:isExclusive]`) for your `RKObjectManager` method. If you do that, it will correctly represent that boolean value as `true` or `false` in the JSON.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot put a fundamental data type in a dictionary. It must be an object. But you can use `[NSNumber numberWithBool:isExclusive]` or use the `@(isExclusive)` syntax:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:genObject
                                       path:@"users/update.json"
                                 parameters:@{
                                              ...
                                             @"em_id"  : ObjectOrNull(em.emID),
                                             @"exclusive": @(isExclusive), ...
```

---

I also don't suspect you meant to use `BOOL *` as your parameter. You presumably intended:

```
- (void)postPrimaryEMWithEM:(EM *)em
                  exclusive:(BOOL) isExclusive
                    success:(void (^)())onSuccess
                    failure:(void (^)())onFailure {
    ...
}
```

Again, a `BOOL` is not an object, so the `*` syntax was presumably not intended.

Comment: also note that `isExclusive` is a `BOOL *`.

Comment: Also remove pointer type from your class declaration: postPrimaryEMWithEM:exclusive:(BOOL)isExclusive.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, I was expanding my answer while you and Greg were posting your comments. Quite right.

Comment: Ok, but the server is expecting a Boolean.

Comment: @jgervin Boolean values sent to your server will be in number format anyways (0 = false/NO, 1 = true/YES).

Comment: @jgervin The `NSNumber` can be used to represent integers, float, double, or boolean values. And when you use `@(isExclusive)` (i.e. the boolean literal), the `NSJSONSerialization` will convert that to a `true` or `false`, just as you'd expect it to.

Comment: @Rob, thanks for pointing that out. Wouldn't the actual request represent true or false in integer value though, or no?

Comment: @Chris No, the JSON would be `{"exclusive":true, ...}`. Or are you saying you want a numeric format?

Comment: @Rob It was an assumption. The business APIs I have worked with always sent and received booleans as integer values. Thanks for the clarification since I was not aware that JSONSerialization did this.

Answer (score 8):

Remove the pointer ('*') form your BOOL:

```
exclusive:(BOOL*) isExclusive
```

and change:

```
@"exclusive": isExclusive
```

to:

```
@"exclusive": [NSNumber numberWithBool:isExclusive]
```

or:

```
// Literal version of above NSNumber
@"exclusive": @(isExclusive)
```

As a note, NSDictionary cannot store primitive types, including booleans. So you have to encapsulate the value in an object, in this case NSNumber.

Comment: Why post a duplicate answer?

Comment: Why post an answer at the same time you mean? I did not see the previous answer when I posted. Should I remove my answer because I did not see a similar one posted?

Comment: You mean about 15 minutes later.

Comment: @rmaddy are you serious? I can read the time. You are making a grand assumption here.

Comment: I am serious. I was commenting on the other answer and saw yours appears roughly 15 minutes after the first one. No assumptions just reality.

Comment: You are still assuming I posted a duplicate answer intentionally by saying "Why post a duplicate answer?"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42720/discussion-between-chris-and-rmaddy)