# How do you pass a Boolean with Restkit

Tags: objective-c, restkit

Anyone using restkit ever pass a boolean back to the server? Can I just pass back a string "true" or "false"?

The server stores the attribute as a boolean.

Comment: As [discussed in your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445375/collection-element-of-type-bool-is-not-an-objective-c-object), use `@(YES)` or `@(NO)` in your dictionary. Or if you have some `BOOL` variable, such as `isExclusive`, use `@(isExclusive)`.

Comment: Doesn't that pass over 1 and 0?  The server doesn't expect 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RestKit](http://restkit.org) uses [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you have a boolean variable, say `isExclusive`, you can add it to your collection object using `[NSNumber numberWithBool:isExclusive]` or with the boolean literal, `@(isExclusive)`. `NSJSONSerialization` will then represent that as either `true` or `false`, as appropriate.

For example:

```
BOOL          isExclusive = YES;
NSDictionary *dictionary  = @{@"exclusive" : @(isExclusive)};
NSData       *jsonData    = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];
NSString     *jsonString  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"JSON = %@", jsonString);
```

That will report:

```
JSON = {"exclusive":true}
```